# VS 2010 Extremely Long Build Path

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors

I am fairly new to Visual Studio (2010). I am following the Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 book and have come to the final chapter of deployment (this is for the sports store app for those who are familiar with it).

Throughout the book I have had no issues on compiling (other than the author errors to be corrected), but now I am a standstill on how to proceed past a compiling issue.

I had changed publish settings to not use a zip file under the build properties. I published the site just fine (I have changed them back and tried to recompile as well). I deleted the outputted files and tried to just do a debug compile and received the error

"The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters."

(File is listed as ASPNETCOMPILER).

I thought to to be a bit odd since my project path is no where near that number.

Well, I looked into the project directory under release and found it generated this wonderful folder structure.

C:\Users\ERIK~1.HED\DOCUME~1\VISUAL~1\Projects\SPORTS~1\SPORTS~1.WEB\obj\Release\Package\Archive\Content\C_C\Users\ERIK~1.HED\DOCUME~1\VISUAL~1\Projects\SPORTS~1\SPORTS~1.WEB\obj\Release\Package\PACKAG~1\Content\themes\base\images

I deleted and recompiled and it still builds this path and gives me the above error.

In the .csproj file I have the following:

```
<Target Name="MvcBuildViews" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(MvcBuildViews)'=='true'">
<AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(WebProjectOutputDir)" />
</Target>
```

But it is the same as all my other projects. I've searched for solutions for similar issues, but found none.

I appreciate any assistance. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try going to Project (menu item) > SportsStore Properties > Build (tab)

Then in the Output section, try browsing to a different folder for your Output path, such as having it build to c:\ drive instead.

Comment: It was a simple fix - everytime I deleted the directories, they reappeared (unsure why VS did this automatically). Had to close VS down and go through each folder, delete contents, then delete folder. Pain in the butt, but worked.